# Is there any generic Hashable typeclass in Haskell? (a.k.a. "deriving (Hashable)")

Tags: haskell, typeclass, hash-function, generic-function

Has anyone written a generic function so that `hash` functions can be generated automatically for custom data types (using the `deriving` mechanism)? A few times, I've written the following kind of boilerplate,

```
data LeafExpr = Var Name | Star deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Hashable LeafExpr where
    hash (Var name) = 476743 * hash name
    hash Star = 152857
```

This could be generated automatically: the basic idea is that whenever adding data, you multiply by a prime, for example with lists,

```
hash (x:xs) = hash x + 193847 * hash xs
```

Essentially, what I'd like to write is

```
data LeafExpr = ... deriving (Hashable)
```

#### Edit 1

Thanks for all of the very helpful responses, everyone. I'll try to add a generic method as an exercise when I have time. For now (perhaps what sclv was referring to?), I realized I could write the slightly better code,

```
instance Hashable LeafExpr where
    hash (Var name) = hash ("Leaf-Var", name)
    hash Star = hash "Leaf-Star"
```

#### Edit 2

Using ghc, **multiplying by random primes works much better than tupling in edit 1**. Conflicts with Data.HashTable went from something like 95% (very bad) to 36%. Code is here: [ http://pastebin.com/WD0Xp0T1 ] [ http://pastebin.com/Nd6cBy6G ].

Comment: Watch out with that multiplication.  The result of overflowing an Int in Haskell is unspecified.

Comment: Adding a `makeHashable` to Data.DeriveTH would be a good TH exercise for someone.  If you're unaware, that would mean you could derive Hashable with `$( derive makeHashable ''LeafExpr)`

Answer (score 2):

How much speed do you need?  You could use one of the packages that use template haskell to generate [serialization](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/derive/derive.htm) code to convert the value to binary and then hash the binary array with [hashable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable).

Comment: If the `LeafExpr`s aren't too big, this would even work with `show`.

Comment: Actually, Hashable on its own has sufficient instances, including for tuples and lists, to let you write an instance for any datatype fairly trivially.